# How i can select class?

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I find certain class using jquery? 
This is my code

```js
$('#reg').click(function() {
  $(".reg-auto").slideToggle();
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(this).find(".reg-auto").offset().top
  }, 2000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="reg"></a>
<div class="reg-auto">text</div>
```

When I click, I want to show certain div.

Comment: what is this certain div

Comment: do you know how to use a hash?

Comment: The question is too vague. do you want to find an element with a class if its present in the DOM ??

Comment: I want to open one div, but not all

Comment: Build an example of your problem in JSFiddle and paste the link here. Offhand however it sounds like you'd have to use something along the lines of `$('#reg').click(function(){$(this).parent().next().slideToggle();});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want - to position the `.reg-auto` to top of the page when `#reg` is clicked

```js
$('#reg').click(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".reg-auto").offset().top
  }, 2000);
});
```

```css
.extra_div {
  min-height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a id="reg">click me</a>
<div class="extra_div"></div>
<div class="reg-auto">text</div>
<div class="extra_div"></div>
```

Comment: extra-div: display: none

Comment: And why so? I have used it to provide some space so that the `animation` effect could be clearly seen.